# NgModules and Router Tree tabs not visible in Augury

Tags: angular, augury

While debugging Angular Project with Augury Chrome Extension, Component Tree tab is present but
 NgModules and Router Tree tabs not visible 
Using Angular 9.1.3 & Augury (1.25.2) as Chrome Extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Augury currently does not have support for Angular Ivy as of Augury v1.